# Number of integral points at minimum distance from n given points in a Cartesian plane

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Given n integral points in a Cartesian plane, I want to find the *number* of integral points which give minimum summary distance from all n points.

*For example*-

let given points be -
(1,3), (2,3), (3,3), (4,3)

then integral points at minimum distance from all the points are-(2,3), (3,3)

with minimum distance of *4* units.

I want to know whether there is a systematic approach to this problem rather than taking mean of all coordinates and checking values greater or less than the mean coordinates.

Comment: Are you measuring the distance in the Euclidean way, i.e. $d( (a,b), (c,d))= \sqrt{ (a-c)^2 + (b-d)^2}$? (Or maybe the taxicab metric?) And by "summary distance" you mean the sum of the distances from each point to your point?

Comment: yes, by summary distance I mean the sum of the distances from each point to that point.
and yes in the Euclidean way, as all the points are integers, does it matter which way I calculate?

Comment: I'm not sure, but my guess is it matters a great deal. Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median#Computation ? It seems to be describe algorithms for finding these points (at least in $\mathbb R^2$, but maybe generalizable to $\mathbb Z^2$) which I would imagine is the best approach to counting the minimizers.